# get error details like at 'openerp application error details'

Tags: python, error-handling, odoo

i'm trying to create error handling in openerp, i use "try - except" method:

```
try:
   bla bla bla
   ...

except Exception,e:
   raise osv.except_osv('Error!','%s'%e)
```

Can i get the error message as completed as openerp application error details (e.g: file.py that containing the error, line number of error, etc)?

Like this one:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/netsvc.py", line 293, in dispatch_rpc
    result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 654, in dispatch
    res = fn(db, uid, *params)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 760, in exp_report_get
    return self._check_report(report_id)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 738, in _check_report
    netsvc.abort_response(exc, exc.message, 'warning', exc.traceback)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/netsvc.py", line 72, in abort_response
    raise openerp.osv.osv.except_osv(description, details)
except_osv: (u'report.faxing.fax', (<type 'exceptions.KeyError'>,   KeyError(u'report.faxing.fax',), <traceback object at 0xb271d20c>))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED!

i just need to use traceback in my code:

```
import traceback

try:
   bla bla bla
   ...

except Exception, e:
   raise osv.except_osv('Error!','%s'%traceback.format_exc())
```

And abracadabra, i'll get what i need..

Hope it usefull to u all too.. :)